# Passing the description text to jquery image slider from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater, eval

I am using a jquery image slider , I have figured out , how to pass the images from database to my image slider , but i m having problems passing the description text to each image because the image formation is in a script and i dont know how to pass the eval("description") to the script. Below is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
              if (!window.slider) var slider = {};
              slider.data = [{ "id": "slide-img-1", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "With up to 30 used caravans for you to choose from, you will soon be able to hit the open road...<br /> Come along and browse at your leisure or take a look at a selection of our current stock." }, { "id": "slide-img-2", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "" }, { "id": "slide-img-3", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" }, { "id": "slide-img-4", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" }, { "id": "slide-img-5", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" }, { "id": "slide-img-6", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here"}];
```

so i want to pass something like "desc":'<%eval("description")%>'

```
<div id="slide-runner"> 

<asp:Repeater ID="rptJquery" runat="server">

<ItemTemplate>
 <a href="">
<img ID='<%#Eval("slideshowID") %>' src='<%#String.Format("/images/slideshow/{0}", Eval("imgURL"))%>' class="slide"/>
</a> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Comment: Is <%#Eval("Description")%> not working with you? I mean did you give it a try ?

Comment: no its not working , i guess u cant use that in javascripting

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this scenario, is to provide your data as JSON and when loading your Image slider, provide this data in the initialization.

The plugin should handle this type of data correctly if you provide it correctly.

if you can tell us the name of your plugin, maybe we can provide some samples for you.

Comment: thnx for ur reple, below is the link of the image gallery which i am using for my project : http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html  , can u plz provide me any tutroial regarding the above scenario